# PaddingTop not working with RelativeLayout

Tags: android

Here in the below code I am giving `paddingTop` inside  the button but it is not working. Here is my code snippet.

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/pPannel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnApps"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Z" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnArtp"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnApps"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="X" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStsm"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnArtp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Y" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumPicker"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnArtp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnStsm"
                    android:text="50%" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please use LinearLayout instead RL

Comment: Ya use LinearLayout...

Answer (score 2):

If you are intended to give space between two buttons then,
use `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` instead of `android:paddingTop="10dp"`

Answer (score 2):

Padding is used to give internal spacing between text and View.. But margin is used to give space between two views..

Instead use this code for give space between two buttons:

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/pPannel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnApps"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Z" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnArtp"
                    android:layout_width="500dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnApps"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="X" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnStsm"
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnArtp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Y" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnNumPicker"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/btnArtp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnStsm"
                    android:text="50%" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

If you have any query, Please let me know.